# Incrementing loops in python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to write a simple python loop that increments, sort of like beats per measure.
I would like to get an output as such: 1 2 3 4, 2 2 3 4, 3 2 3 4, 4 2 3 4 (with each number on its own line)
this is my code, but it is producing: 1 2 3 4, 2 3 4, 3 4, 4

```
    beats_per_measure = 4
    measures = 5

    for beats in range(measures):
        for measure_count in range(beats+1,beats_per_measure+1):
            print(measure_count)
```

Comment: The wanted output is not clear, please provide more information.

Comment: is ` 1 2 3 4,` a continuous number as `1234` or as `1,2,3,4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
beats_per_measure = 4
measures = 5

for beat in range(1, measures):
    print(beat)
    for remaining_beat in range(2, beats_per_measure + 1):
        print(remaining_beat)
```

Comment: yes, exactly. Thank you. I'll make sure I go over this thoroughly and ensure I understand what's happening throughout